# Always sort grouped rows alphabetically in AG Grid

Tags: sorting, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, columnsorting

I am using AG Grid Enterprise edition with unbalanced groups and I'm looking for a way to sort the rows inside the group always alphabetically, and not by the column sorting applied.

In the example below if the users sort by either sum(Val1) or sum(Val2) ASC/DESC in the state group I want the cities to be sorted alphabetically.

https://plnkr.co/edit/VMNY3wHMZ3DlpcJi?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I just took the default example from https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-unbalanced-groups/ and made the columns sortable.

```
public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
   flex: 1,
   minWidth: 150,
   resizable: true,
   sortable: true
  };
```